# Tortoise SVN Commit Failed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise SVN version 1.7.5 at client side. I am trying to commit some files but it gave me an error like - "server sent unexpected return value (400 bad request) in response to put".

It comes with different different files when i am trying to commit again and again.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: why do you still use such an old version? Try TSVN 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

1. Use up-to-date Subversion 1.9 client.
2. Make sure that your antivirus does not interfere with the svn.exe / TortoiseSVN traffic. In some cases on-access or network traffic scanners can cause such issues.